# 404 error page writing to syslog in asp

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, syslog

I have a custom 404 page that is written in classic ASP. I am trying to set up that when the page is hit, it should send a log through syslog. 
How do I write that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log events from Classic ASP using:

```
dim WshShell
set WshShell = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshshell.Logevent 1, "Page not found - your message here!"
set wshshell=nothing
```

You can find more details, such as the different warning levels on [MSDN - Logging Events from ASP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301309).